# shell function doesn't work in subfolder?

Tags: r, windows

I have the following code that should open the Recode.xlsx inside the subf folder but doesn't

```
 write_xlsx(mtcars, "subf/Recode.xlsx")
  shell("subf/Recode.xlsx", wait=FALSE)
```

The following code works, so if anyone has an idea on why it doesn't work it would help me

```
 write_xlsx(mtcars, "Recode.xlsx")
  shell("Recode.xlsx", wait=FALSE)
```

Comment: Try `shell("subf/Recode.xlsx", wait = FALSE, translate = TRUE)`. But actually what you want is `shell.exec`, not `shell`. The fact that `shell` works here at all is purely by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s what the documentation of the `shell` function says (emphasis mine):

> `shell` is a more user-friendly wrapper for `system`. **To make use of Windows file associations, use `shell.exec`.**

And here is another bit of relevant information from the `shell.exec` documentation:

> To be interpreted as relative, the path also needs to use backslashes as separators (at least in Windows 10).

So the following is the correct usage:

```
shell.exec("subf\\Recode.xlsx")
```